# How would I add another shape to the code for pygame so that it moves like one of the other rectangles?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

# Set up pygame.
pygame.init()

# Set up the window.
WINDOWWIDTH = 400
WINDOWHEIGHT = 400
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')

# Set up direction variables.
DOWNLEFT = 'downleft'
DOWNRIGHT = 'downright'
UPLEFT = 'upleft'
UPRIGHT = 'upright'

MOVESPEED = 4

# Set up the colors.
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

# Set up the box data structure.
b1 = {'rect':pygame.Rect(300, 80, 50, 100), 'color':RED, 'dir':UPRIGHT}
b2 = {'rect':pygame.Rect(200, 200, 20, 20), 'color':GREEN, 'dir':UPLEFT}
b3 = {'rect':pygame.Rect(100, 150, 60, 60), 'color':BLUE, 'dir':DOWNLEFT}
boxes = [b1, b2, b3]

# Run the game loop.
while True:
    #Check for the QUIT event.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

     #Draw the white background onto the surface.
    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

    for b in boxes:
        # Move the box data structure.
        if b['dir'] == DOWNLEFT:
            b['rect'].left -= MOVESPEED
            b['rect'].top += MOVESPEED
        if b['dir'] == DOWNRIGHT:
            b['rect'].left += MOVESPEED
            b['rect'].top += MOVESPEED
        if b['dir'] == UPLEFT:
            b['rect'].left -= MOVESPEED
            b['rect'].top -= MOVESPEED
        if b['dir'] == UPRIGHT:
            b['rect'].left += MOVESPEED
            b['rect'].top -= MOVESPEED

        # Check whether the box has moved out of the window.
        if b['rect'].top < 0:
            # The box has moved past the top.
            if b['dir'] == UPLEFT:
                b['dir'] = DOWNLEFT
            if b['dir'] == UPRIGHT:
                b['dir'] = DOWNRIGHT
        if b['rect'].bottom > WINDOWHEIGHT:
            # The box has moved past the bottom.
            if b['dir'] == DOWNLEFT:
                b['dir'] = UPLEFT
            if b['dir'] == DOWNRIGHT:
                b['dir'] = UPRIGHT
        if b['rect'].left < 0:
            # The box has moved past the left side.
            if b['dir'] == DOWNLEFT:
                b['dir'] = DOWNRIGHT
            if b['dir'] == UPLEFT:
                b['dir'] = UPRIGHT
        if b['rect'].right > WINDOWWIDTH:
            # The box has moved past the right side.
            if b['dir'] == DOWNRIGHT:
                b['dir'] = DOWNLEFT
            if b['dir'] == UPRIGHT:
                b['dir'] = UPLEFT

        # Draw the box onto the surface.
        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, b['color'], b['rect'])
    # Draw the window onto the screen.
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

One thing I tried was putting in another item into the list boxes and making it a circle then putting in pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, b['color'], b['circle']) but I keep getting "circle" has no attribute to the module error and I don't know what else to try. I just want to add a circle into the code and apply the DOWNRIGHT( or any of the direction keys) so that it moves around and bounces off the window walls just like the other rectangles

Answer (score 0):

See [`pygame.draw.circle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle). A circle is defined by its center and the radius. e.g.:

```py
b2 = {'rect':pygame.Rect(200, 200, 20, 20), 'color':GREEN, 'dir':UPLEFT}
```

```py
pygame.drw.circle(windowSurface, b2['color'], b2['rect'].center, b2['rect'].width//2)
```

However an ellipse is defined by the bounding rectangle ([`pygame.draw.ellipse`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.ellipse)):

```py
pygame.drw.ellipse(windowSurface, b2['color'], b2['rect'])
```